# Using methods on initialization

Tags: java

I don't know how to ask right question so here's code:

```
public class Foo
{
    private isTrue;

    public Foo() {}

    public Foo setBoolean(boolean b)
    {
        this.isTrue = b;
        return this;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
Foo foo = new Foo().setBoolean(true);
```

OR

```
public class FooTwo
{
    private isTrue;

    public FooTwo() {}

    public void setBoolean(boolean b)
    {
        this.isTrue = b;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
FooTwo fooTwo = new FooTwo();
fooTwo.setBoolean(true);
```

Which one is better/faster/preferred (more used)? Why?

Faster in this particular case - declare and call void or return alredy set Foo.

Comment: It depends what you are doing. If you want this boolean to always be set, then why not take it in to the constructor?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question. You can write `new FooTwo().setBoolean(true);` just like you did for `Foo`.